# ALTER FUNCTION inside IF in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to alter a function only if it exists. I tried this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Information_schema.Routines 
          WHERE Specific_schema = 'dbo' 
            AND SPECIFIC_NAME = 'fnTestFunc' 
            AND Routine_Type = 'FUNCTION')
BEGIN
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTestFunc] (@input VARCHAR(3))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(2)
    AS 
    BEGIN
         --something
    END
END
```

But shows an error

> ALTER FUNCTION must be the single query in the batch

Any idea what is the issue here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to make sure it's compiled and executed in a separate batch. The easiest way here is via `sp_executesql`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Information_schema.Routines WHERE Specific_schema = 'dbo' AND SPECIFIC_NAME = 'fnTestFunc' AND Routine_Type = 'FUNCTION')
BEGIN

EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTestFunc] (@input VARCHAR(3))

RETURNS VARCHAR(2)

AS BEGIN

    --something
END'

END
```

This also avoids another problem - SQL Server wants to compile each *batch* before it starts executing it. But it'd fail to *compile* your original batch if `fnTestFunc` *doesn't* exist. You can't use a *runtime check* (the `IF`) to avoid a *compile time error* - unless you make sure, as above, that the compilation happens *after* the check is completed.

Answer (score 2):

while creating or Altering a Function or stored procedure in SQL Server it's mandatory that the Create / Alter Statement should be the first in that batch.

In your scenario, you can try another approach.

1. Create a Dummy Function / Procedure in the first batch
2. Alter the Procedure/function with your actual logic

Since while altering functions, you can't modify the Return types of the Function, make sure to use the same return type while creating the Dummy function.

Use the Batch Separator `GO` so differentiate between batches

Example

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FnMyFunction') IS NULL
BEGIN

    EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FnMyFunction() RETURNS INT AS RETURN 0')

END
GO

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FnMyFunction()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    <Your Code Goes here>

END
GO
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2016 SP1+, you can skip IF checks and it can be as simple as:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION fnTest()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (1);
END;
GO
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/11/17/create-or-alter-another-great-language-enhancement-in-sql-server-2016-sp1/